# Python multiprocessing Events vs Theading Events

Tags: python, multiprocessing

According to the python 2.7.3 documentation `multiprocessing.Event` is a "clone" of `threading.Event`. However when I use the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Event
test = Event()
test.set()
test.isSet()
```

However I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Event' Object has no attribute 'isSet'
```

What gives? why doesn't multiprocessing Event have a method to check if it is set?

Edit:
Turns out is_set is within multiprocessing Event class... Still the documentation lied

Comment: I guess it's not a good clone.

Comment: `threading.Event.is_set` was added in 2.6 as part of the PEP8-compliance renaming. The old `isSet` was keep purely for backward compatibility purposes. Since `multiprocessing` wasn't added until 2.6, there was no reason to include deprecated names. (If you install the third-party module that the stdlib module is based on, it _does_ have the deprecated names. But I'm not sure why you'd want to do that.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An instance of Event class has `is_set` method. Try this out:

```py
test.is_set()
```

[Here is the documentation for `is_set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event.is_set)